# Existe em Java alguma função equivalente a drawPixel?

Tags: java, swing

Queria saber se existe alguma função em java que plote um pixel, algo parecido com drawPixel ou setPixel que vejo em algumas outras linguagens de programação, em que você informa como parâmetros as coordenada X e Y e a cor de pixel a ser plotado. Não quero funções do estilo drawLine ou algo equivalente.

Comment: Mas um pixel é apenas uma linha muito curta, não existe porque não precisa. As pessoas que criaram a biblioteca entendem profundamente do assunto e decidiram que não era necessário. Se você acha que é precisa mostrar porque.

Comment: @bigown na computação gráfica, cadeira que estou pagando na universidade, pixel não é uma linha muito curta, e sim o menor elemento em um dispositivo de exibição, algo atômico que não se pode quebrar em partes menores. Já uma reta é uma concatenação de pixels. Existe todo um contexto matemático por trás, por isso o problema de usar uma função que esteja no contexto do pixel e não de uma reta. Os professores não gostam de código orientado a "gambiarra".

Comment: E usam Java? (desculpe, não resisti. é só brincadeira).

Comment: Então você vai ter que achar uma solução que os professores gostem. Por sinal nenhuma linguagem de programação moderna que eu conheça possui primitivas gráficas, até porque seria uma gambiarra.

Comment: Brincadeiras à parte, uma olhada no source do drawLine deve ajudar (ou a descobrir como é feito, ou a descobrir um motivo para não ser feito).

Comment: @bigown Java tem bastante disso e estou escrevendo uma resposta agora. :)

Comment: @VictorStafusa tem bastante disso o que?

Comment: Acho que o problema aqui é que a pergunta fala de Java mas tem a tag swing. Pode ser que estejamos pensando em coisas diferentes aqui, e por isso haja alguma controvérsia.

Comment: @bigown, C# tem, queria algo assim
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @DanielMarques Mas a pergunta não é sobre Java/Swing? Em .Net e não em C#, eu sei que existe. Linguagens não possuem primitivas gráficas, bibliotecas sim.

Comment: @bigown, isso foi apenas um exemplo. E sim, quero algo em java/Swing, pois necessito plotar um pixel usando interface gráfica

Comment: @DanielMarques A solução simples que se usa com Swing é o `DrawLine()`, as outras são complexas. Mas você diz que os professores não vão gostar. Então eles não deveriam pedir para usar o Swing. Acho que não posso oferecer outra solução, eu sou pragmático, eu resolvo problemas, quando entra um requisito que não ajuda em nada fica improdutivo procurar por boas soluções.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, com certeza. Você pode usar os métodos [`setRGB(x, y, cor)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB-int-int-int-) e [`getRGB(x, y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-) da classe [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Você pode obter um `BufferedImage` ao utilizar [um de seus construtores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage-int-int-int-), ou carregar uma imagem externa. Por exemplo:

```
BufferedImage imagem = new BufferedImage(largura, altura, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Isso criará uma imagem em branco na memória. O terceiro parâmetro é o tipo da imagem, que no caso do [`TYPE_INT_ARGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB) significa que cada pixel é representado por um `int` aonde os 8 bits mais significativos são o *alpha*, os próximos 8 bits são o vermelho, mais 8 bits do verde, e os 8 bits menos significativos são o azul.

Uma outra forma de se obter uma imagem, é carregá-la de um recurso externo (usando a classe [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)):

```
private static BufferedImage carregarImagem() throws IOException {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(new URL("http://example.com/imagem.jpg"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

Para fazer outras operações mais complexas (desenhar círculos, polígonos, linhas, etc), você pode obter um objeto [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html):

```
BufferedImage imagem = ...;
Graphics2D g2 = imagem.createGraphics();
```

E para desenhar uma outra imagem dentro do seu `Graphics2D` (ou a sua superclasse [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)), você pode utilizar o método [`drawImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-int-int-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-):

```
g.drawImage(imagem, posicaoX, posicaoY, null);
```

Se você quiser desenhar estas imagens na tela (seja para plotar gráficos, ou para fazer jogos com animações), você pode começar sobreescrevendo o método [`paintComponent(Graphics)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-) de qualquer [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html). Por exemplo:

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Coloque aqui sua lógica de desenho.
    }
};
```

Observe que o tipo do parâmetro é `Graphics`. No entanto o AWT sempre irá fornecer uma instância de `Graphics2D`, e neste caso é sempre seguro fazer o cast. Assim, para desenhar um componente (inclusive para fazer animações e jogos), você poderá criar um `BufferedImage`, desenhar nele os pixels que quiser usando os métodos `getRGB(x, y)`, `setRGB(x, y, cor)` e `createGraphics()`, e no final desenhar a imagem resultante no componente:

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(imagem, posicaoX, posicaoY, null);
    }
};
```

Uma sugestão dada pelo @array em um comentário é de usar o método [`fillRect(x, y, largura, altura)` da classe `Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-) (em combinação com o método [`setColor(Color)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor-java.awt.Color-)). Assim se você pode plotar o pixel diretamente no `Graphics` caso você não tenha um `BufferedImage` correspondente facilmente acessível:

```
Graphics g = ...;
g.setColor(...);
fillRect(posicaoX, posicaoY, 1, 1);
```

Comment: eu acredito que possa ser feito algo com o `fillRect`. Exemplo: `fillRect(argX, argY, 1, 1);`. Se você concordar, tem como explicar um pouco sobre isso na sua resposta? Abraços. =]

Comment: @array Resposta atualizada.

Comment: Victor, obrigado. Reputação positiva adicionada. Abraços.